# Question based on relative motion in two dimension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

I came across this problem in my work book.

> A hunter is riding on an elephant of height $4$ $ m$ moving in straight line with uniform speed of $2$ $ m/s$. A deer running with a speed $V$ at a distance of $(4$ $\sqrt{5}$ $) m$ moving perpendicular to direction of motion of the elephant. If hunter can throw his spear with a speed $10$ $ m/s$ relative to elephant, then at what angle to its direction of motion must he thrown w.r.t elephant his spear horizontally for a successful hit. Find also the speed $V$ of deer.

I tried drawing the diagram as shown below : $v_e$ is the velocity of the elephant, $v_s$ is the absolute velocity of the spear and $v_{se}$ is the relative velocity of the spear with respect to the elephant.

[image]

Since the deer is moving perpendicular to the elephant, if the elephant is moving in the $Y$ axis, the deer must have been standing on the $Y$ axis at $(4$ $\sqrt{5}$ $) m$ and running parallel to the $X$ axis. The spear must be thrown at an angle to hit the deer. 
[image]

As the spear and the deer will clearly meet after $t$ seconds, by Pythagoras' theorem

$(v_s . t)^2$ - $(V.t)^2$ =  80

$\lvert v_s \rvert$ = $\sqrt{100+4+40 cos \theta}$

From here, I am unable to proceed. I feel there are too many variables to solve. Could anyone help ?

Comment: "...hunter can throw his spear with a speed $10 m/s$..."

Comment: @YuzurihaInori Sorry, I did not understand. $10$  $m/s$ is said to be the relative speed and not the absolute speed

Comment: There ***are*** too many unknowns. However, you might consider using the extra information of elephant height. The spear is said to be thrown ***horizontally***. The hunter would know what should be the spear's height at impact. Say $1m$. From this, you can gather the time of flight $t$. A bit far fetched solution for a physics problem.